# Excel: how to match 3 columns to 3 different columns to return a value from a fourth column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, spreadsheet

I need to match column D&E&F to W&Y&X to return the value of U to B

I am trying to get an exact match of D2&E2&F2 to W2&X2&Y2 to return the value of U2 (192042722757) to B2.

Google search found:

```
=INDEX(U2:U2141,MATCH($D$1:$D$17&E1:$E$17&$F$1:W1:W2141&X1:X2141&Y1:Y2141,0))
```

Copying and pasting this info is quite tedious, can this be done?

Comment: [A quick search leads to several possible solutions](https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=Excel%20Index%20match%20multiple%20columns)

Comment: If you problem is only copy/pasting the formula, copy the cell in the formula, select the range you want the formula in and paste . Excel should fill the formulas, adjusting them for row/columns (bear in mind you formula has absolute references, so you may need to adjust it)

Comment: You seem to miss a comma between the appended ranges you use: `=INDEX(U2:U2141,MATCH($D$1:$D$17&E1:$E$17&$F$1,W1:W2141&X1:X2141&Y1:Y2141,0))`

Answer (score 0):

- Apply formula on cell B1

```
=XLOOKUP(D1&E1&F1,$W$1:$W$10&$X$1:$X$10&$Y$1:$Y$10,$U$1:$U$10,,0)
```

OR

```
=INDEX($U$1:$U$10,MATCH(D1&E1&F1,$W$1:$W$10&$X$1:$X$10&$Y$1:$Y$10,0))
```

- Fill formula through cell B10

[image]

Comment: May data cells are alpha/numeric, will these formulas still work? I have tried both triple checked my entry and changed formatting from number to general and text and still get "not found. Thank you very much I appreciate your help.

Comment: yes. Please share your data and formula on OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try either of the following formulas:

```
=XLOOKUP(1, (D2=$W$2:$W$2141)*(E2=$X$2:$X$2141)*(F2=$Y$2:$Y$2141), $U$2:$U$2141, "Not Found")
```

OR

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($U$2:$U$2141, MATCH(1, (D2=$W$2:$W$2141)*(E2=$X$2:$X$2141)*(F2=$Y$2:$Y$2141), 0)), "Not Found")
```

With both of these methods, the *lookup_value* is always 1, and the *lookup_array* is a criteria statement that directly compares column D to W, E to X, and F to Y. The result of each condition will return TRUE or FALSE, which when multiplied together will return 1's and 0's. When all three conditions are met, it will return TRUE x TRUE x TRUE, which evaluates to 1 x 1 x 1 = 1. This is more reliable than concatenating the three columns together, as it eliminates the possibility of false matches (ie: {12,0,3} will match with {1,20,3} when using concatenation, as both would evaluate to "1203").

[image: xlookup_multi_cols]

Comment: I have tried both of these and get "not found" my cells consist of alpha/numeric. I think that is and issue. Should you formulas recognize data that is formatted that way. For example

Comment: D2=1066PPH E2=P45 F2=12H

Comment: Yes, it should work regardless of alpha/numeric values. If no match was found, one possible reason is that either one of your *lookup_values* or *lookup_arrays* contain leading or trailing spaces (ie: "1066PPH" does not match "1066PPH "). You could try using the TRIM function on your data to remove any spaces: `=XLOOKUP(1,(D2=TRIM($W$2:$W$2141))*(E2=TRIM($X$2:$X$2141))*(F2=TRIM($Y$2:$Y$2141)),$U$2:$U$2141,"Not Found")`